# Function returning NaN in C++

Tags: c++

I'm creating a software in C++ loops on one function(double) indefinitely. After going through the loop the first time, the second time it runs, it returns 'nan'. Where did I go wrong.

```
int main()
{
   double Balance = 100;

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      nyaradzo(Balance, i);
   }
}

double nyaradzo(double bal, int pass)
{
   int x = bal;
   double Amount;
   string policy_number;
   double confirmation;

   cout<<"WELCOME TO NYARADZO ONLINE POLICY PAYMENT"<<endl;
   cout<<"ENTER YOUR POLICY NUMBER"<<endl;
   cin>>policy_number;
   cout<<"ENTER AMOUNT YOU WISH TO PAY FOR YOU POLICY"<<endl;
   cin>>Amount;
   cout<<"YOUR POLICY NUMBER IS: "<<policy_number<<endl;
   cout<<"YOU HAVE CHOSEN TO PAY $"<<Amount<<" FOR YOUR FUNERAL POLICY. \n Is this information correct?"<<endl;
   cout<<"1 TO CONFIRM"<<endl;
   cout<<"2 TO CANCEL"<<endl;
   cin>>confirmation;
   if (confirmation==1) {
      if (Amount <= x) {
         x -= Amount;
         cout<<"Transaction Complete"<<endl;
         cout<<"YOUR BALANCE IS $"<<x<<endl;
         return x;
      }
      else if (Amount > x) {
         cout<<"TRANSACTION DENIED \a"<<endl;
         cout<<"You cannot withdraw more than your actual balance..."<<endl;
         return 0;
      }
      else {
         cout <<x  << endl;
         cout<<"TRANSACTION DENIED \a"<<endl;
         cout<<"Your purchase must be greater than or at least equal to $1"<<endl;
        return 0;
      }
   }
   else if (confirmation==2) {
      cout<<"YOU HAVE CHOSEN TO CANCEL YOUR ZESA TRANSACTION"<<endl;
      //    transaction(bal, pass);
   }

   else 

{

cout << "Invalid selection" << endl;
return 0;

}
    }
```

When it goes through the loop a second time, it fails.

Comment: `double confirmation;` should be `int confirmation;`.

Comment: What "returns" NaN? You have no `return`s here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not no `return`s. There is a `return` when `confirmation==1 && Amount<=x`

Comment: Did some fix, executed, and got no `NaN`. What is your input? http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/udVqY3jdAr84P3SK

Comment: _@raison jiriyengwa_ You have to provide a `return` statement for every possible path of execution (which you don't). Otherwise you are calling undefined behavior.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Or make the return type of `nyaradzo` to `void` if you don't nead any value to be returned from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all paths in `nyaradzo` return a value. You should enable all your compiler warnings. It should alert you of this. Since `x = bal` and you only modify x when the amout is ok, add this as the final line of the func:

```
return x;
```

And change type of `x` to `double`. Or get rid of `x` and use `bal` throughout.

Also, I assume you want to keep a running balance. Then you should change the for loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  Balance = nyaradzo(Balance, i);
}
```

Comment: This is what I originally had, not working at all. Thanks though

Comment: Finally got it to work after tweaking your code a bit!. Thanks a lot :)